# What's wrong with this mechanics question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Just working through a question and I don't think it's possible to solve without more information. Am I right or am I missing something?

> A 66 kg ice skater comes to rest uniformly on rough ice from an initial velocity of 2.36 ms-1.  Draw a free body diagram of the skater.  What force does friction exert on the skater?  Assume the motion is horizontal.

We know that $u=2.36$, $v=0$, $m=66$ and I should be able to use $F=ma$, but I can't work out $a$ using $u,v$ alone. I need another variable such as $t$ or $a$...

I considered finding the normal reaction, to compute frictional force, but we are not given the coefficient of friction anyway...

Note: apparently the answer is $40N$ in the negative direction, e.g. $-40N$.

(This is not homework)

Comment: If the skater stops there must be a net force. Calculate what that net force must be. Give it a name - "Friction."  Then, if you need to you could calculate the kinetic coefficient, but you don't need it to solve the problem.

Comment: @BillN The only information is that given above. Gravity is acting downwards, so has no bearing on the horizontal forces, except for friction, but we don't know the coefficient of friction. We are given no time or acceleration, or told of any other forces. Are you saying this question can be solved with the given information?

Comment: Ahhh! You could find the horizontal acceleration (the skater is slowing down!) if you knew the distance travelled, and you know the mass, so you coul find the net horizontal force. Yeah, the distance (or the time) is missing.

Comment: Hi Antinous. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic I've added the tag again.

Comment: @BillN Thanks. Yeah, we don't have distance or time I'm afraid. The question is wrong ! Surprising, given it's from a University course someone I know is studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct, you need more information. My first guess was to suggest using the equations of motion for uniform acceleration that you should be aware of, in particular $$v^2 = u^2 + 2 a s,$$ where the symbols have their usual meaning but see that the distance $s$ is not specified.

(By the way, if you were able to determine the (de-)acceleration, and so the frictional force ($F$), you would be able to determine the coefficient of friction from the result $F = \mu mg$.)

Answer (score 1):

Force is equal to rate of change of momentum.

You can find the change in momentum but you do not know the time taken for this change so you cannot find the force with the provided information.